# accessing GUI widgets of one file in different classes pyqt5

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I'm a newbie how do I solve this?

My main question is I'm building a GUI application that has many widgets hence writing all those functions into a single file isn't a good practice hence while writing only I created 2 files I wrote half functionalities in one file and another half in another file (i thought we can connect files and everything will fine) so now I'm trying to make one of the main class and import other all into it  but importing them alone isn't working so I'm confused how to do

my original GUI looks like this
tab 1
[image]

tab 2
[image]

each of these 2 tabs code is written in 2 separate files. and standalone code files workes file so now I want to add something in tab 1 file so tab 2 will also work fine.

**A test GUI and code so someone can try to understand the problem more clearly**

hence I made an example here
with 1 GUI and 2 dropdowns and 2 codes which work standalone for one dropdown
now my question is what are the changes to be done so i can run one file and import all other files info and run all functionality fully from only one file

My GUI (this is a sample made to test)

[image: Image of GUI]

its code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox_select_number">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>240</y>
      <width>311</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Select number</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>1</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>2</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>3</string>
     </property>
    </item>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox_select_gender">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>410</x>
      <y>240</y>
      <width>311</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Select gender</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Male</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Female</string>
     </property>
    </item>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_selected_number">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>195</y>
      <width>311</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>TextLabel</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_selected_gender">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>410</x>
      <y>200</y>
      <width>311</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>TextLabel</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I added 2 combo_boxes and accessing them from 2 different files

I want this class to be the parent/main class
File one code that I want to make as a parent class (for number dropdown)

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys

class Mainn(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Mainn, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("lol.ui", self)
        self.show()

        self.comboBox_select_number.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updatenumber)


    def updatenumber(self):
        number=self.comboBox_select_number.currentText()
        self.label_selected_number.setText(number)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Mainn()
app.exec_()
```

2nd file code for(gender dropdown)

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys

class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("lol.ui", self)
        self.show()

        self.comboBox_select_gender.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updategender)


    def updategender(self):
        gender=self.comboBox_select_gender.currentText()
        self.label_selected_gender.setText(gender)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = UI()
app.exec_()
```

I do know when I run them separately they do only their specific work now I want to combine them so if run the main file both combo box should work suggest me minimal changes of code to work on it.

i do know we can combine like this into a single file and run

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys

class Mainn(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Mainn, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("lol.ui", self)
        self.show()

        self.comboBox_select_number.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updatenumber)
        self.comboBox_select_gender.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updategender)



    def updatenumber(self):
        number=self.comboBox_select_number.currentText()
        self.label_selected_number.setText(number)
    def updategender(self):
        gender=self.comboBox_select_gender.currentText()
        self.label_selected_gender.setText(gender)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Mainn()
app.exec_()
```

and it works
[image]

so I want to get the same functionality with the 2 files by somehow linking them

Comment: Please don't ask the same question just because the first one was closed, especially if its contents are almost the same. As specified in the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67172656/pyqt5-gui-its-components-functionality-in-2-or-more-files), you need to add more details *there* and try to better clarify what you want to achieve. If you believe you gave enough details, then just ask what other information might be needed in the comments.

Comment: @musicamante no sir that question is closed I edited it but it's still closed so reposted with more clear info with test code so someone can test if possible please test once sir and let me know how I can resolve it GUI and both files code has been provided, sir

Comment: @musicamante yes sir I'm ready to provide more info but none commented it was just closed in need of more info no idea what to add so I added more description

Comment: @musicamante sir , given more clarity why I need it with my application images and reasons hope this is a bit clear now

Comment: 1. You should have included the new details in **that** question. 2. reopening can take some time, this is not a payed service, answers don't arrive always in minutes, some questions are even answered after **months**. 3. Asking a question doesn't guarantee an answer; on the contrary, asking again the same question after few hours probably will result in people completely ignoring *both of them*. 4. moderators and users with enough reputation can see deleted posts, and they can become annoyed by such behavior. 5. if you don't know what you can do to improve your question, then *just ask it*.

Comment: @musicamante ok sir really sorry for that. will never repeat it again. is there any more improvement needed / something that needs to be added?

Comment: @musicamante sir shall i delete this and do all the modifications in that old one? or for now, let this be?

Comment: @musicamante sir can u once test and help me with the solution sorry for tagging from the morning I'm trying but unable to solve it.you are the only hope of solution for me Thanks sir

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. If you're asking us to show you how to merge those two files (which are so similar that they don't justify creating two separate script, by the way), then sorry but this isn't how StackOverflow works. We provide solutions to specific questions, not tutorials. Also, you only provided the 2 ui with the combo, and even if we wanted to help you we really couldn't know where they should be added or how (and, most importantly, those are two main windows, and you should not try to add two main windows to another one unless you really know what you're doing).

Comment: Besides that, as said, you **must** be patient: if somebody can answer and wants to, they will **when they want and when they can**. Please consider that continuously asking for help is not really effective, it's just considered annoying (and often results in people ignoring both the request and the question).

Comment: @musicamante like my requirement is that for a single GUI I wrote code in 2 different files which can run standalone(like running them directly will work and only their functionalities which are in it)will run. so now I want to link them by importing or somehow so if I run one file all widgets will work (in example 1 file I wrote code for one Combobox(number) and 2nd file Combobox for gender) so if I run one file both should work. So how exactly to import and what are the changes needed in code to achive it.

Comment: @musicamante yes sir I do understand that but I'm also confused is my question explaining my problem or is there anything wrong

Comment: @musicamante added a working full code. So u check the output like which i need for the test example.sir if ur still confused with question please let me know will try to give more info

Comment: @musicamante sir I have added a solution hope now u get more info and u can clean that code with ease thank you, sir

Answer (score 1):

Hi Finally found a solution
I do know this isn't a good code and it may be completely wrong but I'm getting my required output.

File 1 code

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys

class Mainn(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Mainn, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("lol.ui", self)
        self.comboBox_select_number.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updatenumber)

    def updatenumber(self):
        number=self.comboBox_select_number.currentText()
        self.label_selected_number.setText(number)
```

file 2 code

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys

from main import Mainn

class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(UI, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui=Mainn()
        self.ui.__init__()
        self.ui.show()
        self.ui.comboBox_select_gender.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updategender)

    def updategender(self):
        gender=self.ui.comboBox_select_gender.currentText()
        self.ui.label_selected_gender.setText(gender)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = UI()
app.exec_()
```

now if i run file 2 it works as per my requirement

If still their are any improvements please let me know thank you